# Блокнот глючит

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вставил скопированный из хрома скрипт в блокнот, сохраняю, сворачиваю, получается фигня какая-то:

```
$(function(){$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });$('#tabs').tabs();
```

В одну строку. Это что за свинство?

Comment: О__о подробнее опишите проблему

Comment: извините, ошибку уже исправил...

Comment: хром просто ставил "лишние" переводы строк...

Answer (score 4):

Скачайте [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), например.

Comment: спасибо, скачал. в нём в сто раз удобнее))

Answer (score 0):

Блокнот умеет только переводы строк в формате windows.